# SQL Server Service accounts password

Tags: sql-server, security

We have an environment for DEV, STG and PROD and more than 50 machines.

We have different domain accounts created run each service (SQLServer, Agent, SSRS, SSIS and SSAS), we are planing to changes the service accounts password to make them more strong.

Question is its a good practice to keep changing your service accounts password every to 3 to 4 months?

Few of the best practice I feel good to have are below, are there many more if any one can add will be helpful.

- Use domain account for Service accounts if your VM is a part of domain.
- Don't use single account to all service. For example use different account for different service.
- Have strong passwords set for the Service accounts.

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: is it good to have seperate service account for each product.
For example assume we have 3 products P1, P2, P3 can we have 3 domain accounts for SQLservice to run 
XXXXXX\SQLServiceP1
XXXXXX\SQLServiceP2
XXXXXX\SQLServiceP3

and same way for all other service ( Agent , SSRS, SSIS and SSAS )

Answer (score 0):

Regarding whether it is good practice to rotate passwords - not any more. The reason we did password rotation was that some people performed password cracking on the best machines available in their times (pdp8 in 1979) and it took them about a month to crack them, so other people decided to rotate once every month to mitigate this issue. Since then we have rotated everything blindly forcing humans to go against their nature and choosing crappy passwords as they would be rotated anyway. You rotate passwords when they leak, not when they are used to long.

Other best practice regarding handling passwords can be found here: https://github.com/OWASP/ASVS/blob/master/4.0/en/0x11-V2-Authentication.md#v21-password-security-requirements (Not everything is about service passwords, still many of them are practical for both - service and user passwords).